# Multiple Magento Email Forms & Templates

Tags: php, email, magento

I need to set up multiple email forms on my magento website. I'm including the forms onto CMS pages. They are:

- Arrange a site survey
- catalogue request
- And the default contact form

But you can only select one email template in the admin (system > configuration > contacts). I've got my email templates and included my forms into the CMS pages so I just need them to work.

Comment: Did you make the templates in `System -> Transactional E-mails` ?

Comment: Yup. And I can select it as the email template. But surely i need to specify which email forms link with certain email templates?

Comment: You need to code a controller that receives the form input, loads the template, puts in the data, and sends the email. You can copy some code from the contacts controller. Or search Magento Connect for extensions.

Comment: I thought this may be the case. I havent written my own controller for Magento yet so this should be fun :) lol.

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer I can accept, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a blog post on how to create controller in magento http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller

Comment: i've litrally not no time to do this in now :\, would be be possible to use conditional statements in the defualt email template {{depend ...}} to determin which form was sent and put all the email templates in one file?

Comment: Only $_POST data are  passed to the form template. If you can have a hidden field named "formName", then you can access it in the template like data.formName

Then you can have conditional statement {{if data.formName == 1}}Template for form 1{{else}}Template for form 2{{/if}}

Comment: Great, this seem's an easier and quicker way for me to get this done. I read that you can only use booleans in the conditional statements in the email templates? I need to do 3 contact forms so could i check the string value of formName?

Comment: Apparently yes. But you can still achieve what you want by using the hidden field. Each form can have its own hidden field with different name and the value is "1". then you can do the following in the email template: 
{{if data.form1}}
Template for form 1
{{/if}}

{{if data.form2}}
Template for form 2
{{/if}}

{{if data.form3}}
Template for form 3
{{/if}}

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to create a controller in Magento and don't mind doing something a little more dirty, I would recommend creating a very small module that just had a single controller and then point your forms at that.

Then from there you can use Zend Mail to send the email (easier than trying to use the email templates inside Magento IMHO).